# View and Controller for a Downloadpage

Tags: laravel

I need to create a downloadpage. Ich have a model Product and a model File. The create/store and the edit/update is already working. With a submit button I'm saving fields like produktname, description, etc. into products-table. Fields like filename, filePath and product_id saving into files-table. Files also uploaded to Storage. Model Product has a hasMany-relation to File and the model File has a BelongsTo-relation to Product. In the File model "product_id" is related to the Product model.

So far so good. What's also working is: Index view of FileController. I can see all uploaded files and can also download them. Through the product_id I can access the actual product show method. That's how it should be. It's possible here in the index.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($files as $file)                                         
<tr>                                             
    <th>{‌{ $file->filename }}</th>
    <td><a href="{‌{ $file->filepath }}">download</a></td>
    <td><a href="/products/{‌{ $file->product_id }}">{‌{ $file->product_id }}</a></td>
    <td>{‌{ $file->id }}</td>
</tr>                                        
@endforeach
```

In the show.blade.php I can see already all data from the products table. I have two buttons for downloading changelog (just a link) and working and for downloading the stored file (which is in the files table. I can't get it working for the download stored file. `dd($files);` is NULL. Here's the ProductController show part. I applied `use App\File;` on top of the controller, because I want to give the ability to access the File model.

```
public function show(Product $product)     
{                 
         return view('products.show', compact('product','file'));     
}
```

In show.blade.php I get an error: **compact(): Undefined variable: file**

```
<div>
    <button id="changelog" name="changelog" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="window.open('{‌{ $product->changelog }}')">Download Changelog</button>
    <button id="filename" name="filename" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" onclick="window.open('{‌{ $file->filename }}')">Download Installer</button>
</div>
```

How can I access an element of the other model or the other table? How can I expand `{‌{ $file->filename }}` or probably  `{‌{ $product->$file->filename }}` to get the file to download?

I'm trying since days and can't find the solution.

Comment: Please attach your Product Model and File Model

Comment: Because you didn't define the `$file` variable on `show` function

Answer (score 0):

Thx, for responding. I still have problems doing Eloquent and Query building, but the use of dd od var_dump helps alot and showed me that I have valuable data. The problem was to define the query.
Here's the working stuff:

**Product model**:

```
public function file()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\File', 'product_id');
    }
```

**File model**:

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Product', 'id');
    }
```

**Product controller**:

```
public function show(Product $product)
    {
$files = Product::with('file')->find($product->id)->file;
return view('products.show', compact('product', 'files'));
    }
```

**show view**:

```
@foreach ($files as $file)
      <button id="filepath" name="filepath" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" onclick="window.open('{{ $file->filepath }}')">Download File:  {{ $file->filename }}</button>
@endforeach
```